# Why I cannot use BASE in my inheritance

Tags: c#, windows, inheritance

Exactly this code: compile error says use of base is not valid in this context.

```
public class UCMComboBoxCellType : FarPoint.Win.Spread.CellType.ComboBoxCellType
{
    public UCMComboBoxCellType()
    {
        base();
        this.ListWidth = 0;
    }
}
```

but why? I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C# you chain constructors like this:

```
public UCMComboBoxCellType() : base()
{        
    this.ListWidth = 0;
}
```

What you tried is the Java way.

Comment: There is no point though.  If the base class has a parameterless constructor it will get called implicitly.

Comment: @Joe: Why? well I want to use this new class in my code instead of ComboBoxCellType class that I had used before. so it does not work this way?

Comment: By virtue of being a derived class, all constructors in the chain will necessarily get executed.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't.

If you needed to call a parameterized baseclass constructor, you'd do so like so:

```
public MyClass(string msg)
    : base(msg)
{
...
}
```

but in a parameterless case, there is no need -- it is implied that the derived constructor will call the base class constructor first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class UCMComboBoxCellType : FarPoint.Win.Spread.CellType.ComboBoxCellType
{
    public UCMComboBoxCellType() : base()
    {
        this.ListWidth = 0;
    }
}
```